# difference between 'introduction to' or 'introduction of'

Tags: single-word-requests

I will be giving an introduction to Historians or introduction of Historians. Which one is correct? 'to' or 'of'?

Answer (score 1):

It depends:

> An introduction **of** historians (the people about to come on stage or in your story).
>
> An introduction **to** historians (the audience, or something you will make place for).